# How can I open multiple links using a single anchor tag

Tags: html, anchor

So here's a simple but interesting question, how can I open multiple links using single `<a>` element?

Using this only opens the first `href`

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can certainly try this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HGy3f/)

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com'); window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: For anchors on the same page, use something like,  onclick="location.href='#top'"

Comment: Always open only the 1st link not both. It is like that even in the demo. Only open the google page but not yahoo

Comment: blocked by popup blocker.. any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I searched for that but unfortunately all methods I found don’t work.
I have one way to that with JS (but one linkwill open in the current tab):

HTML Code:

```html
<a id="myId">go</a>
```

JS Code:

```js
myId.onclick = function(){
   open('https://www.example1.com');
   location.href = ('https://www.example2.com');
}
```

So here it will open example1.com in another tab.

Then in the current tab, will open example2.com

Note: The order of JS Lines is required otherwise it will not work.