# how to open more than one tab using Anchor Tag

Tags: html, css, anchor

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com'); window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');">Click Here</a>
```

In this, when clicking the link, the **popup** are opening.
But i want to open both in the **new tab** . Help me in solving the problem.

Comment: this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965753/how-can-i-open-multiple-links-using-a-single-anchor-tag

Comment: Add some more detail about your query..

Comment: @json ...sir i just want to open two URL in tab by just single link. But the code above opens the link in new window not in new tab....So, please modify the above code so that it open 2 link in new tab not in windows.

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya .... Sir i have posted the same code which you are refering me.......But,i want modification in it (i.e opening of 2 url in new tab not in new popup windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method:

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com'); window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');">Click Here</a>
```

Answer is also available at 
[How can I open multiple links using a single anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965753/how-can-i-open-multiple-links-using-a-single-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this no longer works in the major browsers to prevent spam.

As at October 2020:

- Chrome: Opens the first onClick link only.
- Firefox: Opens the first onClick link, then displays a banner saying "Firefox blocked a popup from opening.
- Safari: Working ok. All tabs open.

Comment: So there's no getting around this at all?