# In ASP.NET how to write a <a> tag into another <a> tag

Tags: html, asp.net, anchor

Here is the HTML code I want to write in the output page:

```
Response.Write ("<a href=\"page2.aspx\">Page2" + 
                "<a href=\"page3.aspx\">Page3</a></a>");
```

I expect the following output:

```
<a href="page2.aspx">
  Page2
  <a href="page3.aspx">
    Page3
  </a>
</a>
```

But I get the following one:

```
<a href="page2.aspx">
  Page2
</a>
<a href="page3.aspx">
  Page3    
</a>
```

Does anyone know why `Response.Write` closes the  tag and how to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML forbids nested anchors.

> Content model:
>   Transparent, but there **must be no interactive content descendant**.

— [The `a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Either ASP is cleaning up your markup, or you are looking at in a DOM inspector after the browser has tried to recover from your error.

Comment: Exactly, I would like to know if ASP modify my page or if it's my browser which correct this forbidden nested anchor. When I write the expect HTML code myself, firefox displays it correctly.

Comment: Easy enough to tell: Use View Source instead of a DOM inspector. And firefox doesn't display it "correctly", there is no "correctly". Stop trying to write invalid HTML.

Comment: Nice, View Source confirms that ASP doesn't modify my page. It's my web browser which does it. It's all the firefox fault, which respects the HTML rules. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot nest `a` element inside another `a`, HTML doesn't allow that, it's invalid, browser will just parse them as separate `a` tags.

[As Per W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)<sup>1</sup>

> <sup>1</sup> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be
>   nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.

---

If you are looking to open multiple links on a single anchor tag, consider using `onclick` event with `window.open()`, refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13965765/1542290) for more details.

Comment: Ok, I see, nested anchors are forbidden in good practices. But it works if I write the HTML myself (firefox manage it). So my question is why the `Response.Write` method modify my string (may be, just because it's forbidden to nest anchors :) ). Thanks for the `onclick` it's agood idea.