# Pass data to 2 pages using one <a> tag

Tags: php, url, anchor, href

I have to pass an ID in  tag to two different pages.

My current code is:

> `<a href="select1.php?id=<?php echo $cval['id']?>">Edit</a>`

I need to pass to ***select1.php*** and ***select2.php***

Trying to do something like

> `<a href="select1.php?id=<?php echo $cval['id']?> && select2.php?id=<?php echo $cval['id']?>">Edit</a>`

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965753/how-can-i-open-multiple-links-using-a-single-anchor-tag) . But it doesnt solve my issue.

Comment: Is there any other `<a>` tag other than this or you are trying to open two pages with one `<a>` tag

Comment: Please do well define question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask..

Comment: @AnshuSharma No.This is the only <a> which Iam trying to pass my ID to 2 different pages.

Comment: <a href="select1.php?id=<?php echo $cval['id']?>" onclick="location.href='select2.php?id=<?php echo $cval['id']?>';" target="_blank">Open Two Links With One Click</a>

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar I tried this. But it got redirected to select2.php alone and not to select1.php

Comment: @jumbo you can added this target="_blank because it's work fine in my browser

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Sounds like you are trying to solve a problem, but doing it in a way which complicates things more. If you explain what problem you are trying to solve, then maybe we can help you find a better solution.

Comment: Iam trying to a pass an ID to 2 different pages.

Comment: When people ask you what exactly you want to achieve, then they usually expect a different response, than you simply repeating what you already said. _Why_ do you want this, what is the _purpose_? Explain what _action_ needs to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');
    window.open('http://yahoo.com');">Click to open Google and Yahoo</a></p>
```

**Do note that this will be blocked by popup blockers built into web browsers but you are usually notified of this**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://yoursite.com/select1.php?id=<?php echo $cval['id']?>');
window.open('http://yoursite.com/select2.php?id=<?php echo $cval['id']?>');">Edit</a>
```

Comment: The value is passed only to select1.php page and not to select2.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following-

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="window.open('select1.php?id=<?php echo $cval['id']?>;');  window.open('select2.php?id=<?php echo $cval['id']?>;');">Edit</a>
```

**There will be a pop-up blocker while trying to open two windows so you need to set this on allow**