# your page was not found (HTML, bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have done it right. use the # sign before the ID so that the navbar link will works. why do "Your file was not found" appear?
I will include my HTML codes :

```
<

!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Van-tag</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href=" nav-link" href="#footer"> Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="nav-link" href="#pricing"> Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="nav-link" href="#cta"> Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Here is the link of my full HTML codes. maybe it will helpful.
https://code.sololearn.com/WI5eJj8HKGqH/#html

Comment: What URL you are trying to visit?

Comment: I'm still newbie, please pardon me. it's still raw website so it did not hosted.

Comment: the url is the ID section.

Comment: <a href=" nav-link" href="#footer"> Contact</a>

Comment: <a href="nav-link" href="#pricing"> Pricing</a>

Comment: <a href="nav-link" href="#cta"> Download</a>

Comment: on another hand, my mentor used to this href="#(ID)" method and it worked! i wonder why

Comment: It would help you to read a bit more about anchor tags. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21397285/13290801

Answer (score 1):

In order to link to a section of your current page you would need to remove the second href tag

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#footer"> Contact</a>
</li>
```

If you would like to have to multiple links on one anchor tag you could try something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13965765/9427907

You can read more about `anchor` tags here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21397285/9427907

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how your site is set up, but you have a couple of ways of pointing somewhere in a link:

1. an absolute normal link to another page:

   `<a href="https://www.example.com/myPage.html">Link Text</a>`

Here you point at your domain and to the page you want to load.

2. a relative link to another page:

   `<a href="myPage.html">Link Text</a>`

Note that in this case the file mySite.html has to be in the same folder as the page you are linking from. Otherwise you have to specify the path as well (e.g. `mysubfolder/myPage.html`)

3. an anchor tag:

   `<a href="#myAnchor">Link Text</a>`

In this case you need an anchor on the very page yo are on so the link knows where to jump to. Any `id` tag with the right name will work. `<div id="myAnchor">Content</div>`

4. a mixture of both

   `<a href="myPage.html#myAnchor">Link Text</a>`

In which case the file `myPage.html` has to have the `<div id="myAnchor">Content</div>` so the link can find the place it is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create a link to go another page, you can create a new file html first and linked

```
<a href="newPage.html">Go new page<a/>
```

You can create an "internal" link, to go a section o your page, linked with an id attributte, like this:

```
<h3 id="#internalLink">Section to go</a>

<a href="currentPage.html/#internalLink">Go to section</a>
```

This link could be useful [Html Links Hyperlinks](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)